# how to iterate the json objects in the jsonarray

Tags: java, json

hi everyone i wrote a Deserialize code has shown below

```
public class JsonDataDeserialisation implements JsonDeserializer<JsonData>{

    @Override
    public JsonData deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JsonObject jobj = json.getAsJsonObject();
        String jsontype = jobj.get("type").getAsString();
        String jsonname = jobj.get("name").getAsString();
        String jsondoc = jobj.get("doc").getAsString();
        Fields[] fields = context.deserialize(jobj.get("fields"), Fields[].class);
        JsonData jdata = new JsonData();
        jdata.setType(jsontype);
        jdata.setName(jsonname);
        jdata.setDoc(jsondoc);
        jdata.setFields(fields);
        return jdata;
    }

}
```

for the json event given.

`{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Doc",
  "doc": "adoc",
  fields: [{
    "name": "id",
    "type": "string"
  }]
}`

but when it comes to multiple objects in an fields array like

`{
  "type": "record",
  "name": "Doc",
  "doc": "adoc",
  fields: [{
    "name": "id",
    "type": "string"
  }, {
    "name": "id1",
    "type": "string1"
  },: {
    "name": "id2",
    "type": "string2"
  }]
}`

i tried this code and it show me the

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: JsonObject error

```
public class JsonDataDeserialisation implements JsonDeserializer<JsonData>{

    @Override
    public JsonData deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context)
            throws JsonParseException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        JsonObject jobj = json.getAsJsonObject();
        String jsontype = jobj.get("type").getAsString();
        String jsonname = jobj.get("name").getAsString();
        String jsondoc = jobj.get("doc").getAsString();

        Fields[] fields = context.deserialize(jobj.get("fields"), Fields[].class);
        JsonArray fields1 =jobj.get("fields").getAsJsonArray();
        String[] fieldst = new String[fields1.size()];
        for(int i=0;i<fieldst.length;i++){
            JsonElement jsonfields = fields1.get(i);
            fieldst[i] = jsonfields.getAsString();
        }
        JsonData jdata = new JsonData();
        jdata.setType(jsontype);
        jdata.setName(jsonname);
        jdata.setDoc(jsondoc);
        jdata.setFields(fields);
        return jdata;
    }

}
```

where am i going wrong please help me out thankyou

Comment: I suggest you to use JsonObject instead of JsonElement in the following loop: 
`for(int i=0;i<fieldst.length;i++){
            JsonElement jsonfields = fields1.get(i);
            fieldst[i] = jsonfields.getAsString();
        }`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20832015/how-do-i-iterate-over-a-json-response-using-jackson-api-of-a-list-inside-a-list

Comment: `JsonObject f1 = context.deserialize(jobj.get("fields"), Fields[].class);
  String[] fields = new String[f1.size()];
  for(int i=0;i<fields.length;i++){
   JsonObject jsonfields = (JsonObject) f1;
   fields[i] = jsonfields.getAsString();` itried this for iteration but it says` [LFields; cannot be cast to com.google.gson.JsonObject` this error how to read each object in fields array please give me some example